# How to switch to the second page?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list that changes the content as I press a button, what happens is that when it reaches the last content I wanted it to open up a specific page. How can I do this?

The button:

```
TextButton(
                child: Text(
                  "Próximo",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(82, 126, 255, 1.0),
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                 
                    ++_currentIndex ;
                   
                  });
                }),
```

The list:

```
class ScreenData {
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  final String image;
  final int duration;

  const ScreenData(this.title, this.subtitle, this.image, this.duration);
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
  bool startStop = true;

  static const List<ScreenData> _data = [
    ScreenData("Saltar à corda", "Próximo: Subir à cadeira", "assets/images/1.gif", 15),
    ScreenData("Subir à cadeira", "Próximo: Flexões", "assets/images/abdominais.gif", 10),
    ScreenData("Flexões", "Próximo: Abdominais", "assets/images/flexoes.gif", 10),
    ScreenData("Abdominais", "Próximo: Prancha", "assets/images/1.gif", 10),
    ScreenData("Prancha", "", "assets/images/prancha.gif", 25),
  ];
  int _currentIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do so we:

1. Can check whether we reached the last content;
2. Use the power of `Navigator` to navigate to the new screen.
   By using the following snippet:

```
TextButton(
  child: Text(
    "Próximo",
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(82, 126, 255, 1.0),
      fontSize: 18.0,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () {
    if (_currentIndex >= _data.length - 1) { // We reached the end!
      Navigator.push(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPageScreen()),
      ); // Let's navigate to the new page!
      return;
    }
    setState(
      () {
        ++_currentIndex;
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use navigator

```
 Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => AllCategoryItems(),
                    ),
                  );
```

in this example, i have a stateful class named AllCategoryItems(it can be stateless it doesn't matter) you have to put it inside your onpressed function

Answer (score 0):

```
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {               
    ++_currentIndex ;
  });
  If(_currentIndex == _data.last) {
    /// your navigation code
  }
}),
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.